# Not able to find out the IBM NLU latest syntax for Python

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-nlu

I am trying to connect IBM Watson NLU using python but below code is outdated because today I have created the new resource group for the IBM NLU then I tried to find out the credentials but I didn't get the username and password.

There are new things.
Please check the below image.

[image]

```
    natural_language_understanding = NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1(
        url=<URL>,
        version='2018-03-16',
        username=<UserName>,
        password=<Password>)

    natural_language_understanding.disable_SSL_verification()
    try:
        response = natural_language_understanding.analyze(
            text=str(user_answer_sent),
            features=Features(
                semantic_roles=SemanticRolesOptions(),
                sentiment=SentimentOptions()
            ), language='en'
        ).get_result()
```

I am not able to find out the latest syntax for IBM Watson NLU.  Please let me know if you have then I will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are additional examples and more information in the [API reference](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/natural-language-understanding/natural-language-understanding?code=python#authentication).

Answer (score 1):

Please check out the [Python SDK for the IBM Watson services](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk). It includes [sample code for IBM Watson NLU](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/blob/master/examples/natural_language_understanding_v1.py) which shows how the new [Authenticator model](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk#iam) is used. It is something like:

```
import json
from ibm_watson import NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1
from ibm_watson.natural_language_understanding_v1 import Features, EntitiesOptions, KeywordsOptions
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator

# Authentication via IAM
authenticator = IAMAuthenticator('your_api_key')
 service = NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1(
     version='2018-03-16',
     authenticator=authenticator)
 service.set_service_url('https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-understanding/api')
```

Comment: I tried above code but i got the below error:-  __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'authenticator

Comment: Have you installed ibm-watson and other required modules?

Comment: Check the entire sample code as linked from the answer